# C# Escape sequence for unicode currency symbols

Tags: c#

I'm storing a list of currencies, with exchange rates etc. in my database (Ms SQL).

I also store the unicode representation of the currency symbol, so for e.g. Czech Republic, Koruny I have `"\u004b\u010d"` stored in an nvarchar(50) column.

When I load the list of currencies from the database, it has changed to escape sequence to this: `"\\u004b\\u010d"`.

Is there any way easier than stripping away \u, parsing the remaining part to an Int32 using System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber, type casting that to a char and displaying the char?

Comment: This is bizarre. Why not just set it as the character itself? That's the point of the `n` in `nvarchar`, right?

Comment: True. I guess I was blinded by the site where I found the symbols. They had unicode and hex decimals for every currency, so I just copied that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is an `nvarchar` column you could store directly the corresponding unicode value: `Kč`. Why would you ever store it as `"\u004b\u010d"`?